# Web scraping tennis odds

Tags: python

I am attempting to scrape the following web page

https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/wta-singles/dubai/siniakova-katerina-kvitova-petra/6ZCipZ9h/#ha

I am fine with scraping player names, the date, the score, however, I am running into trouble when trying to scrape the match odds of the different bookmakers (listed in the table)

Here is what I attempted

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/wta-singles/dubai/siniakova-katerina-kvitova-petra/6ZCipZ9h/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

Odds = soup.find_all('td', attrs= {'class':'table-main__detail-odds table-main__detail-odds--first'})

print(odds)
[]
```

As you can see, nothing is being found.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Comment: That's because that html doesn't have class that you're looking for.

Comment: That makes sense. But when I inspect the element on the page, that is the class that comes up??

Comment: To add to @hod's comment: the data you're attempting to grab appears to be loaded by page-executed Javascript. You'll likely need to pivot to using Selenium or similar to fully emulate a typical browser and execute the Javascript your scrape relies on before attempting to grab the data you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The class you seem to be looking for is `table-main__odds` as per the page source.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/tennis/wta-singles/dubai/siniakova-katerina-kvitova-petra/6ZCipZ9h/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

odds = [x.attrs for x in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'table-main__odds'})]
print(odds)
```

Output:

```
[{u'class': [u'table-main__odds'],
  u'data-odd': u'3.46',
  u'data-odd-max': u'3.90'},
 {u'class': [u'table-main__odds', u'colored']},
 {u'class': [u'table-main__odds'],
  u'data-odd': u'3.58',
  u'data-odd-max': u'3.92'},
 {u'class': [u'table-main__odds', u'colored']}]
```

Comment: This only seems to capture the average odds and the maximum odds